# IDs in Two Columns - Find One ID and Retrieve Other ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

This question has probably been asked before, but I haven't found it. I have a PostgreSQL table with IDs in two columns.

```
user_left | user_right | 
-----------+------------
   1      |       2    | 
   2      |       3    | 
   4      |       2    |
```

If I select user `2`, I'd like to return something like:

```
users | 
------+
   1  | 
   3  |  
   4  |
```

I know I will have to `join` something, but what I've tried (`inner joins`, `outer joins`) baffles me. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Part of a [mcve] is a clear specification--a description of how the result you want is a function of the input. But you don't give one. We only have an example so we can only guess what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select user_left
from t
where user_right = 2
union all
select user_right
from t
where user_left = 2;
```

You can also use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when user_left = 2 then user_right else user_left end)
from t
where 2 in (user_left, user_right);
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I might have to resort to using `union all`, but didn't consider `case`. Both examples are helpful.